# Terraform Values from `.tfvars` are being ignored when using Multi Level Maps

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am not getting any error, but values from `.tfavrs` are being ignored and values from `variables.tf` are being loaded. In `.tfavrs` it has three Instances (**test-vm1**, **test-vm2** and **test-vm3**) and `varibale.tf`  has two instances (**test-vm1** and **test-vm2**), when I run terraform plan, I only see **two Instances (test-vm1 and test-vm2) being created**.  Both `varibale.tf` and `gcp_instance/variable.tf` have the same content. I request you to help me correct my `.tfvars` or suggest me achieve my goal

Commands I am executing

```
terraform plan  -var-file=customers/nike.tfvars
terraform apply -var-file=customers/nike.tfvars
```

**Folder structure**

```
├── gcp_instance
│   ├── gcp_instance.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
├── customers
│   └── nike.tfvars
└── variables.tf
```

**.tfvars**

```
gcp_project             = "test"
gcp_region              = "us-central1"
gcp_zone                = "us-central1-a"
gcp_network             = "default"
gcp_network_global_cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"

gcp_credentials = "test.json"
instance_tags   = ["app", "non-prod"]

instance_config = {

  test-vm1 = {
    instance_name  = "test-vm1"
    instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    instance_type  = "n1-standard-4"
  },

  test-vm2 = {
    instance_name  = "test-vm2"
    instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    instance_type  = "f1-micro"
  },

  test-vm3 = {
    instance_name  = "test-vm2"
    instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    instance_type  = "f1-micro"
  }

}
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "gcp_project" {
  description = "Google Cloud Platform project"
  default     = "o9-ops"
}

variable "gcp_region" {
  description = "Google Cloud Platform's selected region"
  default     = "us-central1"
}

variable "gcp_zone" {
  description = "Google Cloud Platform's selected Zone"
  default     = "us-central1-a"
}

variable "gcp_credentials" {
  description = "Credential file to be used for this project"
  default     = "test.json"
}

variable "instance_tags" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["app", "deploy"]
}

variable "instance_config" {

  type = map(object({
    instance_name  = string
    instance_image = string
    instance_type  = string
  }))

  default = {
    test-vm1 = {
      instance_name  = "test-vm1"
      instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
      instance_type  = "n1-standard-4"
    },

    test-vm2 = {
      instance_name  = "test-vm2"
      instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
      instance_type  = "f1-micro"
    }
  }
}

variable "gcp_network" {
  description = "Network to be used"
  default     = "default"
}

variable "gcp_network_global_cidr" {
  description = "CIDR for the Instances"
  default     = "10.128.0.0/20"
}
```

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  region      = var.gcp_region
  project     = var.gcp_project
  zone        = var.gcp_zone
  credentials = var.gcp_credentials
}

module "gcpinstance" {
  source                  = "./gcp_instance"
  instance_tags           = var.instance_tags
  gcp_network             = var.gcp_network
  gcp_network_global_cidr = var.gcp_network_global_cidr
}
```

gcp_instance/gcp_instance.tf

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {

  for_each = var.instance_config

  name         = each.value.instance_name
  machine_type = each.value.instance_type
  tags         = var.instance_tags

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = each.value.instance_image
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = var.gcp_network
  }
}
```

Comment: Terraform won't automatically load files that aren't called `terraform.tfvars` or `*.auto.tfvars`. You either need to specify the vars file with `-var-file` or you need to rename your file.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes, I am actually specifying the file, while executing the plan and apply command. I updated my question. still same issue

Comment: You aren't passing `var.instance_config` into your `gcpinstance` module so it's ignoring it. I'm assuming you have a similar default `var.instance_config` in the module which is what is confusing you but you didn't show your variable definitions for the module in the question.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks a ton! after adding var.instance_config to gcpinstance. its is working